# How to add default head block in default.xml

Tags: layout, phtml, custom-theme, php-7.2, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to add default head block in default.xml file. so if anyone have idea about it then please send me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For custom module use following.

  app/code/{{vendorname}}//{{modulename}}/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

and add css or js like as follows

```
<head>
    <link src="{{vendorname_modulename}}::js.js"/>
    <css src="{{vendorname_modulename}}::css/yourstyle.css"/>
</head>
```

- Without module if you need in your theme do like this.

  Create following file under your theme

  `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
  And add following code in your xml

Answer (score 2):

Create `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" src_type="url" />
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 641px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />

        <script src="Magento_Theme::js/init.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="{{vendorname_modulename}}::js/yourjs.js"/>
    <css src="{{vendorname_modulename}}::css/yourstyle.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```